# Problem with Statsbomb xG shot map (Soccer /football) Shot not plotting according to the desired location

Tags: python

So I have a small issue. I extracted the shot location, xG, outcome for the Tunisia-England World cup game.

And I wanted to make a shot map out of it.

so I imported it and wrote this:

```
    data = pd.read_csv('TN_EN_WC18.csv')

data


XY = []

for i in range(len(data['location'])):
  XY.append(re.sub('[^\d\.\ ]', '', data['location'][i])) 
for i in range(len(XY)):
  XY[i] = XY[i].split(' ')




pitch = Pitch(pitch_type='statsbomb', pitch_color='#0f1029', line_color='White')
fig, axs = pitch.draw(figsize=(10, 8))


for i in range(len(data['team'])):
  if data['team'][i] == 'England':
    if data['shot_outcome'][i] == 'Goal':
        pitch.scatter((XY[i][0]), (XY[i][1]), s=((data['shot_statsbomb_xg'][i])*1000),  c="#33ff69", ax=axs)
    else:
        pitch.scatter((XY[i][0]), (XY[i][1]), s=((data['shot_statsbomb_xg'][i])*1000),  c="#ff4433", ax=axs)


fig.suptitle('title', fontsize=20, color="White", fontweight='bold', fontfamily="Monospace")
fig.set_size_inches(15, 7)
fig.set_facecolor("#0f1029")

plt.show()
```

But then the shots are plotted in one corner of the pitch like that:

[Shot Map](https://i.stack.imgur.com/cKymA.png)

Data frame:

```
    location | shot_statsbomb_xg | shot_outcome | team
0   [113.0, 39.0]   0.393783    Saved   England
1   [108.0, 41.0]   0.029620    Off T   England
2   [97.0, 36.0]    0.036681    Blocked England
3   [112.0, 47.0]   0.052105    Saved   England
4   [116.0, 46.0]   0.240122    Goal    England
5   [94.0, 48.0]    0.018643    Saved   England
6   [91.0, 21.0]    0.018489    Off T   Tunisia
7   [116.0, 50.0]   0.154092    Off T   England
8   [98.0, 46.0]    0.030076    Blocked Tunisia
9   [108.0, 36.0]   0.027045    Wayward Tunisia
10  [111.0, 58.0]   0.007516    Saved   England
11  [108.0, 40.0]   0.760000    Goal    Tunisia
12  [118.0, 47.0]   0.086920    Blocked England
13  [117.0, 37.0]   0.289248    Wayward England
14  [114.0, 39.0]   0.356160    Wayward England
15  [106.0, 41.0]   0.138739    Blocked England
16  [108.0, 54.0]   0.320665    Post    England
17  [112.0, 40.0]   0.055357    Saved   England
18  [106.0, 40.0]   0.016941    Wayward England
19  [93.0, 27.0]    0.060391    Off T   England
20  [106.0, 60.0]   0.027727    Blocked Tunisia
21  [93.0, 43.0]    0.020467    Off T   Tunisia
22  [96.0, 34.0]    0.088615    Off T   England
23  [116.0, 36.0]   0.258531    Goal    England
```

Sorry its a little off since I copy/pasted it.

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 0):

The issue is you are feeding a string as your x and y coordiantes, Ie. `'113.0'` and `'39.0'` instead of floats of `113.0`, and `39.0`.

Change this:

```
XY = []

for i in range(len(data['location'])):
  XY.append(re.sub('[^\d\.\ ]', '', data['location'][i])) 
for i in range(len(XY)):
  XY[i] = XY[i].split(' ')
```

To this:

```
XY = []
for each in data['location']:
    XY.append([float(x) for x in re.sub('[^\d\.\ ]', '', each).split()])
```

In fact, I would actually simplify this code a bit as there are a few loops and unnecessary variables and functions. See if the below makes sense to you.

**Full code:**

```
data = pd.read_csv('TN_EN_WC18.csv')

pitch = Pitch(pitch_type='statsbomb', pitch_color='#0f1029', line_color='White')
fig, axs = pitch.draw(figsize=(10, 8))

team = 'England'
england_data = data[data['team'] == team]
for idx, row in england_data.iterrows():
    X, Y = [float(x) for x in re.sub('[^\d\.\ ]', '', row['location']).split()]
    color = "#ff4433"
    if row['shot_outcome'] == 'Goal':
        color = "#33ff69"
    pitch.scatter(X, Y, s=((row['shot_statsbomb_xg'])*1000),  c=color, ax=axs)
    
    
fig.suptitle(team, fontsize=20, color="White", fontweight='bold', fontfamily="Monospace")
fig.set_size_inches(15, 7)
fig.set_facecolor("#0f1029")

plt.show()
```

**Output: with your sample data:**

[image]

Comment: I tried but it didn't work. I'm putting the dataframe I used in case you need it to understand better.

Comment: @AnasSouabni your sample data helped. See updates solution.

Comment: Oh thanks! Thank you very much! Yeah it makes more sense.

Comment: The only thing is I didin't know many of these functions in order to shorten the code.

Comment: Ya no worries! I put them in there so you could see. Best way to learn is to see various ways to achieve the same output.